# How many files Sqlite create on a new db creation?

Tags: .net, sqlite

Ifw e are creating a database with name "MyDatabase" then it will create a file "MyDatabase.sqlite" on a specified directory. 
**Will any other file or files (supporting or temp) also be created. IF yes then what will be the name and location of these files?**

Note- C# application is creating database on Windows 7

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html

Answer (score 1):

SQLite stores the entire database in a single disk file.

Source: http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html

Internally, SQLite uses some temp files but most of users don't have to worry about that since they are created and deleted by SQLite engine. AFAIK, those file are located in the same folder as SQLite file.